# Can we change stage size dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, resize, flash-cs6

Am working on flash cs6 and AIR 14.I developed one app i want to adjust that app to all android and ios devices.for that i want to change my stage size dynamically according to screen resolution of device.Is it possible to do that.if yes how ?

Comment: Yes, it's technically possible (that's the answer to 99% of such questions). "How" is rather broad.  Have you tried anything (e.g. starting a project and testing it on two different devices)?

Comment: You dont change the stage size, that changes by itself due to environment. Checking stage width on a small phone screen will give a different number compared to same code running from a larger "pad" screen. You need to put content into container (movieclips) and change their sizes against the available stage size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

First thing you need to do is the following: (as soon as your application has access to the stage)

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align     = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

This will make your stage not scale and become the full size of it's container - in your case an AIR window.

For mobile AIR, this will make it the screen resolution of the device.  Though on some high-density displays (iPhone) by default you may get half the native resolution of the device, but scaled x2 so it's still fullscreen.  You can adjust this when you build the application in AIR if needed.

For desktop AIR, you can programmatically change the stage by resizing the `NativeWindow`.

```
stage.nativeWindow.width = 1234;  //set the width of the stage's window (which will in turn set the stage size if scaleMode is NO_SCALE)
```

Comment: I Am using stage size 1350*768.The above  code working fine for resolution nearly 768*1024.but i instaled app in ipad 3 having resolution 1536 x 2048.for this resolution the all movieclips in that game are compresed but game visible in total window.But i dont want to compress the movieclips and images in game.how can i solve give me any suggestion.@LDMS

Comment: What do you mean by "compressed"?  Do you mean they look smaller?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Compression means for example take one image width is 170.if you decrease width 170 to 120.now see that image how look like.note decrease only width not height.am getting that shape for all movieclips in game.am getting this issue for all very high resolution like 1500*2000.I need to do any scaling ?@LDMS

Comment: So you're saying the aspect ratio is off and everything looks a little squished?    Here is a decent article from Adobe you may find useful: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html